# Write the output to same output Excel File

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am doing web scraping and I am writing the output of data frames to a new Excel workbook every day. I want to add the output of each day to already existing excel file and I have no idea of how to do so. Can anyone please help me with`` this!!!

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output'+dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.xlsx')
for each in channel_id:
        start_time=0
        start_time = time.time()
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        a=get_all_video_in_channel(each)
        print(len(a))
        df=df.append(get_links(a),ignore_index=True)
        df = df.set_index('link').transpose()
        #print(df)
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet'+str(count))
        writer.save()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        count=count+1
```

The above is the small snippet of the code for writing the data frame into an excel file (One day).I want the same excel file to be used every day.

Comment: Do you want to data to the same sheet? a different sheet for every day? How's the separation between days is done?

Comment: check the openpyxl library, you can do cell referencing in that and will be able to append the data at specific positions.

Comment: I want in the same sheet @Shir

Answer (score 0):

Use `openpyxl`:

Suppose you have an existing `excel file-- 'output'+dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.xlsx'` with Sheet name `Sheet1`. You can do something like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('output'+dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output'+dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=None, startrow=1, header=None)
writer.save()
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: What is the exact error? You can use my code as a template. You might need to tweak it as per your needs.

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output2018-10-31.xlsx'

Comment: Give the file requisite permissions. This is not my code's fault. This error should have come when you did this `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output'+dte.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.xlsx')`.

Comment: Ya exactly I am just doing that Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to provide the file permissions I have tried many ways but it still says the same !

Comment: Try: `chmod +w <file-name>`

Comment: It works like this os.chmod('output.xlsx',0o755).Thanks for the idea though!!

Comment: Great. Now you have permissions on the excel. Try out my code.

Comment: Ya I have modified the code accordingly but thanks for the help

Comment: Did my code help? Were you able to write into the same excel?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook_name = 'C:\\your_path\\Book1.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(workbook_name)
page = wb.active

# New data to write:
child = [['one','two','buckle my shoe'], ['three','four','open the door']]

for info in child:
    page.append(info)

wb.save(filename=workbook_name)
```